# Springboot large file upload throw "Out Of Memory"

Tags: java, spring-boot, upload, large-files, embedded-jetty

I am using **Springboot (2.x) with Jetty Server** and trying to **upload MULTIPLE large files(~2.2GB) PARALLEL** to S3 via direct Streaming, still getting `Out Of Memory` Issue. So, my question is `Is SpringBoot loads InputStream in memory?` Since I am not loading InputStream in memory.

**Controller Class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/{customerId}/{uniqueDocId}/files")

public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    private FileService fileService;

    @PostMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UploadFileResponse> uploadFile(
    @RequestParam InputStream file,
    @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH) final long contentLength) throws IOException {

    FileUploadInput input =
            FileUploadInput.builder().file(file).contentLength(contentLength).build();
        try{
            return ResponseEntity.ok(fileService.uploadFile(input));
        } finally {
            if(input.getFile() != null) {
                input.getFile().close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
@Servive
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

  @Autowired
  private AmazonS3 s3Client;

  @Override
  public void uploadFile(FileUploadInput input) {
    try {
      ObjectMetadata objMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
      objMetadata.setContentLength(input.getContentLength());
      PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest =
          new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3Key, input.getFile(), objMetadata);
      s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
    }
  }
}
```

**application.properties file:**

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size: 5GB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size: 5GB
```

**Below Hardware Details where I am running my SpringBoot Application:**

```
Memory:3G
Disk:5G
```

**Question:** Even I am directly Streaming from the client to the SpringBoot app to S3. Then Why SpringBoot is throwing `out of memory` even though I have set server multipart properties?

**I have also tried to change InputStream to Multipart. Still, I am getting the same problem.**

**Stack Trace:** Only the below logs are visible in the console then the app crashes.

```
2023-07-26T12:51:26.988+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Exit status 137 (out of memory)
2023-07-26T12:51:26.990+05:30 [CELL/SSHD/0] [OUT] Exit status 0
```

Comment: hello, Any additional information in the stacktrace? Maybe you could paste it also in your question?

Comment: I have added a stack trace. Nothing much is showing in the logs. Only `out of memory` is coming and then the app is crashing.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to increase the size of the Heap.

```
1GB as initial heap size [-Xms1024M ]

5GB as maximum heap size [-Xmx5120M ]
```

Comment: I don't think so it's saying the Java heap out of memory. But anyway Increasing memory is a workaround. Since my question is why the `out of memory` issue is coming since I am not storing stream in memory and even setting the spring properties also.  And why I am saying setting higher memory is just a workaround since if multiple large files of 5GB will be hit to the app then 5GB memory also will be less for the app.

Comment: The aim is to stream the data through with a more or less constant memory footprint no matter how large the files are, so this is not the correct solution to this problem.